# How to get unique values in the self join and how to get LIMIT number dynamically in psql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am just learning databases and practising my skills on the table shown below:

```
id  |       name        | wins | matches 
-----+-------------------+------+---------
 205 | Twilight Sparkle  |    0 |       0
 206 | Fluttershy        |    0 |       0
 207 | Applejack         |    0 |       0
 208 | Pinkie Pie        |    0 |       0
 209 | Rarity            |    0 |       0
 210 | Rainbow Dash      |    0 |       0
 211 | Princess Celestia |    0 |       0
 212 | Princess Luna     |    0 |       0
```

My Job is here is Returns a list of pairs of players for the next round of a match. Assuming that there are an even number of players registered, each player appears exactly once in the pairings.  Each player is paired with another player with an equal or nearly-equal win record, that is, a player adjacent to him or her in the standings.

*Returns:*
A list of tuples, each of which contains (id1, name1, id2, name2)
id1: the first player's unique id
name1: the first player's name
id2: the second player's unique id
name2: the second player's name

To achieve those goals I have done self joined that table and have written code something like this:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b.id, b.name 
FROM results AS a, results AS b 
WHERE a.id > b.id and a.wins = b.wins 
LIMIT COUNT(a.id)/2;
```

It seems it is not working. How can I deal with this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or PostgreSQL? - they are two different RDBMS's

Comment: I am using PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sequence them based on their wins then join on the sequence, so they may have the same wins or next closest:

```
WITH seq_results AS
(
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY wins DESC) AS seq
FROM
    results
)

SELECT
    r1.id,
    r1.name,
    r2.id,
    r2.name
FROM
    seq_results r1
JOIN
    seq_results r2
    ON  (r1.seq = (r2.seq - 1))
    AND (r2.seq % 2 = 0);
```

Per your request, here is some information on how this works. I will highly recommend that you visit the documentation for PostgreSQL - it really is some of the best documentation out there: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/

The first part is a common-table expression (CTE). It allows me to essentially create a table in-memory for use in subsequent queries. You could just as easily create a temp table, but these don't have to be dropped, etc.
See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

```
WITH seq_results AS
(
SELECT
    id,
    name,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY wins DESC) AS seq
FROM
    results
)
```

In this CTE, I am sequencing/sequentially numbering each record using a window function. I will use these numbers later in my join. See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html

```
SELECT
    r1.id,
    r1.name,
    r2.id,
    r2.name
FROM
    seq_results r1
JOIN
    seq_results r2
    ON  (r1.seq = (r2.seq - 1))
    AND (r2.seq % 2 = 0);
```

Above I am joining the CTE to itself using the sequence. I "offset" the sequence of the second instance of the CTE `r2` by -1, essentially joining two sequential records together.

Had I only specified that condition in the join, I would return more than the 4 records expected. I needed to make sure that the ids and names on the "left" are not also on the "right", so I decided to include only the odd-numbered sequenced records on the left and the evens on the right. To do this, I used the modulus operator `%` to ensure that `r2` only returned records where the sequence was even.

Lastly, because the join was an inner join (`JOIN` is the same as `INNER JOIN`), any even-numbered sequences in `r1` are not returned.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would preface the query with `create table`, but the logic is correct.

Comment: What is there not to understand about that? The table `seq_results` is used twice in the final query, so it cannot be a CTE.

Comment: Hi, i am getting this error   `ValueError: For eight players, swissPairings should return 4 pairs. Got 3`  i think some one are missing in the list i have tried left join but i am getting 8 pairs. I think more then 2 people were having same scores.

Comment: Hi, i am getting this error   `ValueError: For eight players, swissPairings should return 4 pairs. Got 3`  i think some one are missing in the list i have tried left join but i am getting 8 pairs. I think more then 2 people were having same scores.

Comment: Where is this error from? `ValueError: For eight players, swissPairings should return 4 pairs. Got 3`

Comment: @Nicarus it is not matching correct way from 8 participants each time 2 players should play the game which have same winning score . In this error is telling that my program tested with 8 players table , this code is only producing 3 matches instead of 4(2 people in a single match).

Comment: _Where_ is the error coming from? I doubt PostgreSQL returns this exact error. Are you running this through some other software - possibly for a homework assignment?

Comment: OK. When you run this query on your own - how many records return? 3 or 4?

Comment: i got 3 rows 3 rows.

Comment: Does every player have 0 wins, as shown in your question?

Comment: no they might change according to the test code. I think what missing is this code is not able to match players approximate wins( not the same number of wins)

Comment: @Nicarus  WOW that was awesome. Thank you very much for your help. And if you can please explain your code ?? because i am just beginner i can't able to understand how that code worked especially  `  ON  (r1.seq = (r2.seq - 1))
    AND (r2.seq % 2 = 0);` .. Again Thank you soo much for your help.

Comment: Sure, I will update it with some more information in a few.